# Problema con un model en Codeigniter3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

No consigo solucionar este error, estuve leyendo que es por un problema de minúsculas y mayúsculas, no me reconoce el modelo codeigniter 3

Nombre Modelo : Model_Usuario.php
Nombre Controlador : Usuario.php

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Usuario extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Model_Usuario');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['contenido'] = "usuario/index";
        $data['selPerfil'] = $this->Model_Usuario->selPerfil();
        $this->load->view("plantilla", $data);
    }
}


<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Model_Usuario extends CI_Model{   
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }

        //funcion de de select
        public function selPerfil(){
            $query = $this->db->query("Select * from perfil");
            return $query->result();
        }
 }


<h4>Crud - CI3</h4>

<?php
    print_r($selPerfil);
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías agregar el nombre del archivo de tu controller y de tu model

Answer (score 0):

Debes de declarar la clase de tu modelo son su nombre en minusculas, con excepción de la primera letra

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {.....}
```

a lo cual tu fichero debe ser `application/models/User_model.php`

al cargarlo sobre el controlador todo en minusculas

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
```

No se si te funcione intentando hacer esto en tu código

```
$this->load->model('model_Usuario');
```

Comment: no funciona, tengo el mismo problema y no puede soluciarlo..

Answer (score 0):

Lo tienes así: `class Usuario extends CI_Controller {`

Debe ir así: `class Usuario extends CI_controller {`

Igual en el Modelo lo tienes así: `class Model_Usuario extends CI_Model{`

y debe ir así: `class Model_Usuario extends CI_model{`

Comment: Hola Enrique, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, te sugiero que edites tu respuesta, y la corrijas, ya que has repetido los nombres que sugieres cambiar, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.